# How to prevent sorting dynamically

Tags: ag-grid

In my `AgGrid` I am marking the grid as `dirty` if I have a modification in it. If it's `dirty===true` then I want to popup a dialog if somebody is trying to sort the columns asking whether to really sort the column. So I need a way **how to suppress sorting**.

I think I could use an event `beforeSortChanged` but it doesn't provide me with any params. I haven't found any handlers to suppress sorting/filtering either. Is there any means to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ag-grid-react` so I had to do 2 things:

```
<AgGridReact 
  ...
  enableSorting="true" // REMOVE THIS LINE
/>
```

and

```
this.gridOptions = {

    onCellValueChanged(){
        this.isDirty = true;
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.isDirty = nextProps.isDirty;
    this.gridOptions.enableServerSideSorting = !this.isDirty;
}
```